# React js error on production Minified React error #301

Tags: reactjs

On Production getting this error cant able to resolve.

react-dom.production.min.js:216 Error: Minified React error #301; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=301 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

In react site saying due to re rendering but our code not much re rendering. This issue blocking our application. its happening only in our production environment

Comment: You are caused a re-render loop somewhere in your application, probably caused by a bad `useEffect` or something of sorts.

Comment: It sounds like your first step needs to be either getting more information about the error (perhaps a stack trace which pinpoints the relevant component) and/or replicating the error in a development environment (even if it involves pointing that environment at production data and replicating the exact steps).  The error message itself is simple enough, a component is re-rendering indefinitely.  Aside from telling you what the error message *means*, there's nothing we can do to help you solve it without more information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Today I am facing the similiar issue. Fisrt I run the code in develop mode and the console will show more detail info about this issue, in my situation. The develop mode shows error info:

```
Error handled by React Router default ErrorBoundary: Error: img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`
```

I put some child element in img tag like this:

```
{avatarUrl ? <img className="avatarImg" src={avatarUrl} onClick={avatarClick} /> : <img className="avatarImg" src={avatarImg} onClick={avatarClick} >Me</img>}
```

remove the `Me` will fixed this issue.